# cout<<"\n\n any key to continue or Ctrl+Z to exit."; how to hide the pressed key?

Tags: c++

At the end of my loop I have:

```
cout<<"\n\n  any key to continue or Ctrl+Z to exit.";
```

It allows the user to continue entering data, or to exit by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>. I would like to hide the pressed key when  the user decides to continue entering data.

I don't want the pressed key to appear when the user press any key to stay in the loop. How can I do that? I am using Dev-C++. the code of my function is below.

```
void student::read()
{
    char response;  ofstream OS ("student.dat", ios::app);

    do
    {
        cout<<"Name: ";
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"Age: ";
        cin>>age;
        cout<<"GPA: ";
        cin>>GPA;

        //calling writefile to write into the file student.dat
        student::writefile();
        cout<<"\n\n  any key to continue or Ctrl+Z to exit."<<endl<<endl;

        cin>>response;
        cin.ignore();

    }
    while(cin);  //Ctrl+Z to exit
}
```

Comment: Rather than displaying the message once in each iteration, why don't you display it once at the beginning of the function? This way, you don't have to prompt the user for a confirmation key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are multiple ways to handle this

but it depends on what operating system you are using

http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcurses/curses.h.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h

Option 1:
Windows using conio.h

```
  getch()
```

or for *nix using curses.h

```
getch()
```

Option 2:
In Windows, you can turn off echo for any standard input function with SetConsoleMode().
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  HANDLE hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); 
  DWORD mode = 0;
  GetConsoleMode(hStdin, &mode);
  SetConsoleMode(hStdin, mode & (~ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT));

  string s;
  getline(cin, s);

  cout << s << endl;
  return 0;
 }//main
```

or *nix syle

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   termios oldt;
   tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
   termios newt = oldt;
   newt.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
   tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);

   string s;
   getline(cin, s);

   cout << s << endl;
   return 0;
 }//main
```

Comment: One problem remains, I cannot exit anymore with Ctrl+Z. how can I keep Ctrl+Z as the unique exit of that program?

Comment: do you need Ctrl-Z or you can just use something like 'q' to quit and then you could 
    while (strcmp(input, 'q') != 0)

Comment: The assignment requires us to terminates with Ctrl-Z.